# Magento 2 : API Get Customer Cart Data using customer ID

Tags: magento2, api, addtocart

I am building custom magento 2 API. I want to get customer **CART DATA** using **CUSTOMER_ID**.

I have tried following code but its not working.

```
$params = $this->request->getPostValue();
$customerId = $params["customer_id"];
        
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

//Code to get customer cart data
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
$customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId); // where `$customerId` is your `customer id`
return $items = $customerQuote->getAllItems();
```

I have also tried many other sample codes but they are not working anyone can help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....

}

$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customer);
$items=$quote->getAllItems();
```

Where `$customer` is customer `object (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer)`

```
   var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Thanks hamendra for your suggestion.. This give error ( ie.  https://prnt.sc/wenabo  ) of [[   main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5ff0571b73c05; 
Message: Class stri does not exist  ]]  any suggestion ??

Comment: are you getting customerobject ?

Comment: Yes ie. https://prnt.sc/wenovq